# Space lost on the left side of math symbol

Tags: latex

The space between individual words on the left side of my arrow symbol is lost. I have read a few posts suggesting that I was missing this:

```
$[symbol]$
```

However, the problem is still not solved.

```
C^+ = CGDE, so C is not a superkey and C $\,\to\,$ GD violates BCNF. \\
```

The output:

[image: output]

Thank you!

Comment: You mustn't use `^` in normal text mode. If you would look at your log file you would see an error telling you this. Unrelated to your problem: don't misuse `\\ ` for line breaks

Answer (score 1):

I will include here inline and display (equation) mode solutions:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$C^+ = CGDE$, so $C$ is not a superkey and $C\to GD$ violates BCNF.

\[
C^+ = CGDE\textrm{, so }C\textrm{ is not a superkey and }C\to GD\textrm{ violates BCNF.}
\]

\end{document}
```

These both are just sketches and may well be refined. Please comment further so we can adapt these to your needs together.

Ah, to obtain a line break out of math mode in the output file, do not use `\\` as in tables but insert an empty line in your code!

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that `$…$` is deprecated (?) in LaTeX and should be replaced by `\(…\)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph For inline math `$...$` is ok, just `$$...$$` for display math is deprecated

Comment: @samcarter I had the distinct impression that there was a plan to also deprecate `$…$` in LaTeX 3. Maybe that was scrapped, or I misremember (it’s been a long time for me). But as I’m sure you know (though maybe you disagree?) it’s definitely *discouraged* by many LaTeX users and developers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thank you. I generally rely on [this explaination](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/513/49683).

Comment: @KonradRudolph I don't think we need to be worried about things deprecated with LaTeX3 anytime soon :)